# A Far Eastern Poem

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, poetry

> You insist I should take one
> Ten I shall take as I won.
> Tendencies are like a corpse
> Fire spreads over entire course.
> Fighting as they found a hole
> Bamboos grow on land as whole.
> Bamboozling, I take villages
> Golden signs lie over ages.
> Golfers shall smell a fragrance
> Horses show what they will glance.
> Horizons pointed by a deer
> Black as Guinness, oh my dear.
> Blocked by traps for tiny mice
> Arranged evenly like dice.
> Arrogant as they show teeth
> ______s those I hid beneath...

What's the hidden word? It has 6 letters.

My first enigmatic puzzle, enjoy!

Subtle Hint:

> Each line holds exactly one clue. Except the last line.

Moderate Hint:

> Something accumulates one by one, line by line.

Decisive Hint:

> If this poem had a 17th line, its last word would be "flute."

Very Decisive Hint:

> You insist to mark a dot
>  Knives are to hit the spot.
>  Knights holding up their shields
>  Water floods over their yields.
>  What treat they're having is sweet
>  Rice is the meal they will eat.
>  Right then, the side-dish is peas
>  Doors open for their good peace.
>  Dominating all the wind
>  Ghosts just laugh at what they wind.
>  Gospels are for ripe barleys
>  Yellow and fresh on trolleys.
>  Yelling at that one cauldron
>  Noses they pick as they drone...

Very² Decisive hint:

> The word is an animal, a mythical one.

Comment: 'mark a dot', 'cauldron', and other terms make me think of Macbeth, but that's all I've got. There's something going on with the letter repetition and rhyming, but no conclusions.

Comment: @Amoz Err, sorry. Nothing to do with Macbeth. Should consider the title.

Comment: Perhaps you should add a bounty and bump this? It's sad to see such a nice puzzle go unnoticed...

Comment: Is it 6 letters with the s or without?

Comment: @Taco Without the "s".

Comment: @DannyuNDos can you tell me if I'm overthinking or on the right track in any particular areas while I continue looking? This is my third attempt at this puzzle.

Comment: @Taco Sorry, but nothing to do with the number of spaces or letters. The pattern is something much exotic, yet straightforward. Should consider the title.

Comment: @DannyuNDos thanks! I'll keep looking; I'm going to keep my partial answer around while I work on it. Oh, also, was my guess for the word correct? That *might* help me identify the pattern I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tacoタコス: Please don't pester the OP with requests for hints. Judging from your answer, my impression is that you are nowhere near to solving this puzzle. If you can't solve it, you can't solve it. That's life.

Comment: I updated my answer based on ExtraFishness' answer and your comment towards radicals. Is it correct?

Comment: @Taco: I'm sure OP will be notified about your edit, so no need to comment. Your latest edit is a complete rewrite so that your answer now is essentially ExtraFishness's answer, reformatted with links and with a correction that OP posted in comments. Are you trying to reap your own bounty here?

Comment: @MOehm no I want the bounty to go to ExtraFishness, but the OP said their answer was “essentially correct” with an incorrect explanation. I want to know the intended answer for this, regardless of the bounty. Thanks for reminding me to assign it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word we're looking for is:

> 龍 or Dragon
>  Each line contains *one* word, that as a Chinese radical, contains one more stroke than the word from the prior line.
>  <sub>*See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kanji_radicals_by_stroke_count) for the complete list of radicals that powered this answer.*</sub>

---

##### Line by Line

"*You insist I should take one*"

> The word *one* is represented by the radical [一](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E4%B8%80), which has 1 stroke.

"*Ten I shall take as I won.*"

> The word *ten* is represented by the radical [十](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E5%8D%81), which has 2 strokes.

"*Tendencies are like a corpse*"

> The word *corpse* is represented by the radical [尸](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E5%B0%B8), which has 3 strokes.

"*Fire spreads over entire course.*"

> The word *fire* is represented by the radical [火](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E7%81%AB), which has 4 strokes.

"*Fighting as they found a hole*"

> The word *cave* is represented by the radical [穴](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E7%A9%B4), which has 5 strokes.

"*Bamboos grow on land as whole.*"

> The word *bamboo* is represented by the radical [竹](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E7%AB%B9), which has 6 strokes.

"*Bamboozling, I take villages*"

> The word *village* is represented by the radical [里](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%87%8C), which has 7 strokes.

"*Golden signs lie over ages.*"

> The word *gold/metal* is represented by the radical [金](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%87%91), which has 8 strokes.

"*Golfers shall smell a fragrance*"

> The word *fragrant* is represented by the radical [香](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%A6%99), which has 9 strokes.

"*Horses show what they will glance.*"

> The word *horse* is represented by the radical [馬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%A6%AC), which has 10 strokes.

"*Horizons pointed by a deer*"

> The word *deer* is represented by the radical [鹿](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%B9%BF), which has 11 strokes.

"*Black as Guinness, oh my dear.*"

> The word *black* is represented by the radical [黑](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%BB%91), which has 12 strokes.

"*Blocked by traps for tiny mice*"

> The word *mouse/rat* is represented by the radical [鼠](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%BC%A0), which has 13 strokes.

"*Arranged evenly like dice.*"

> The word *even/uniformly* is represented by the radical [齊](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%BD%8A), which has 14 strokes.

"*Arrogant as they show teeth*"

> The word *teeth* is represented by the radical [齒](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_211), which has 15 strokes. This is actually the *only* radical with 15 strokes.

"*______s those I hid beneath...*"

> The word *dragon* is represented by the radical [龍](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E9%BE%8D), which has 16 strokes.

##### Final Note

This answer was heavily driven by the [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/111848/51105) given by [@ExtraFishness](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76152/extrafishness), so make sure you upvote theirs too.

> The *only* disconnect with their answer is that they focused on Japanese radicals. The Japanese radical for *dragon* is 竜, which only has 10 strokes.

Comment: Before you downvote, please take the time to leave a comment explaining what you didn't like about my post so that I can improve it. Additionally, keep in mind that partial answers are acceptable.

Comment: rot13(Ovt uvag: Guvf thrff vf pbeerpg.)

Comment: @DannyuNDos Abj gb cebir jul. Gunaxf!

Comment: It seems like this answer really isn't based on anything in the actual puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi it’s based on the title and the final hint, and OP confirmed it’s correct, but I can’t seem to prove *why* it’s correct.

Comment: With relation to the poem itself.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is

> Dragon

The reasoning is that

> Each line contains a word that when translated to Japanese kanji will have one more stroke than the last line. on odd numbered lines it is the last word, and on even numbered lines it is the first.

> one: 一(1 stroke), ten: 十(2 strokes), corpse: 尸(3 strokes), fire: 火(4 strokes), hole: 穴(5 strokes), bamboo: 竹(6 strokes), village: 村(7 strokes), Gold: 金(8 strokes), fragrance: 臭(9 strokes), Horse: 馬(10 strokes), Deer: 鹿(11 strokes), Black: 黑(12 strokes), Mice: 鼠(13 strokes), Arrange: 摒(14 strokes), Teeth: 齒(15 strokes)

> until we get to line 16. There are a lot of kanji with 16 strokes, but the hints say that this is a mythical beast from the far east, and the poem references gold, razed villages, teeth and fire, so we arrive at the kanji for Dragon: 龍(16 strokes).

Comment: rot13(V qvqa'g fghql Wncnarfr xnawv naq V nz va ab jnl na rkcreg, whfg yhpxrq bhg jvgu n thrff. V hfrq guvf xnawv qvpgvbanel: uggc://erqsvapuwncnarfr.pbz/?npgvba=xnawv_qvpgvbanel gb svaq nyy gur jbeqf, ohg V qvq unir gb vzcebivfr n ovg jvgu fvathyne sbezf bs jbeqf naq guvatf yvxr sentenapr juvpu genafyngrq vagb fgvaxvat (yby). Ubcr V tbg zbfg bs gur jbeqf evtug)

Comment: Aha, that looks very good! But rot13(V jbhyq rkcrpg gung gur nqqrq fgebxr jbhyq zbqvsl gur cerivbhf xnawv flzoby, abg whfg nqq gb gur gbgny ahzore bs fgebxrf. Bgurejvfr, ubj jbhyq lbh xabj gung gur jbeq vf qentba? Jr xabj abj, bs pbhefr, ohg gur bevtvany dhrfgvba whfg nfxf sbe n jbeq.)

Comment: rot13(Gur uvagf fnl gung vg'f n zntvpny ornfg sebz gur rnfg fb gung znxrf frafr, nyfb gur ersreraprf gb enmrq ivyyntrf, sver, grrgu naq fb sbegu... ohg cbvag gnxra, V jvyy nqq gung cneg gb gur nafjre nf jryy :)

Comment: Well, if this isn't correct, it must be _very_ close. Perhaps OP can explain in detail.

Comment: I'm sure I missed some things and I would love to see OP's take on this as well

Comment: I have just noticed that rot13(sbe bqq yvarf vg vf gur ynfg jbeq naq ba rira yvarf vg vf gur svefg jbeq, fb gur xnawv sbe qvpr jnf vapbeerpg, vafgrnq vg vf gur xnawv sbe neenatr.)

Comment: Essentially right, but the explanation is inaccurate. Hint: rot13(enqvpnyf)

Comment: Well done! How did you get to rot13(Wncnarfr)? We’re there others you looked at first, or thought about?